# Should I put enrollment into but not starting study in resume?

Tags: job-search

Suppose I am now leaving my current graduate school without succeeding in my PhD, and get enrolled into another school starting in spring next year. I will continue to search for a job in the gap between. If I can find a job, I may not continue my study in spring. During job hunting and on my resume, shall I mention that I am enrolled into the other school but haven't started yet? Thanks!

Comment: I have, but temp work is impossible for me because I need working visa. If I can get a job before spring starts, I will go for the job, not starting study.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> During job hunting and on my resume, shall I mention that I am
>   enrolled into the other school but haven't started yet?

If you are honestly committed to taking a long-term job if you can find one, and not continuing with your education, then the fact that you happen to have a backup plan (being enrolled in a school) isn't really relevant.

Thus, I **wouldn't** put it on my resume.

Your visa status may be relevant, however, and probably deserves a mention on your resume and/or cover letter.

Answer (score 6):

Ask yourself how it would help you get hired if they know this. The answer is that it would be a **negative** (he's leaving soon and won't be committed to stay here) not a positive. Since you may stay if you get a good job, it is foolish to tell them something that may not happen which would only make it harder for an employer to decide to hire you for anything that is not temporary. If you were looking for temp work, it might be a different answer.